# what is `search` in the example of filtering options in angular manual

Tags: angularjs

What is `search` in the expressions `search.$`, `search.name` and `search.phone` in the examples given [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter):

```
<table id="searchTextResults">
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
    <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
Any: <input ng-model="search.$"> <br>
Name only <input ng-model="search.name"><br>
Phone only <input ng-model="search.phone"><br>
Equality <input type="checkbox" ng-model="strict"><br>
<table id="searchObjResults">
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friendObj in friends | filter:search:strict">
    <td>{{friendObj.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friendObj.phone}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer based on what I get.

Comment: Yeah, I've figured out that already myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out it myself. The expressions `ng-model="search.$"`, `ng-model="search.name"` and `ng-model="search.phone"` create an object on the scope with properties `$`, `name` and `phone`:

```
$scope.search = {
    "$":"",
    "name":"",
    "phone":""
}
```

Then the doc explains that the search expression here `{{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator}}` can have a form of an object:

`Object: A pattern object can be used to filter specific properties on objects contained by array. For example {name:"M", phone:"1"} predicate will return an array of items which have property name containing "M" and property phone containing "1". A special property name $ can be used (as in {$:"text"}) to accept a match against any property of the object. That's equivalent to the simple substring match with a string as described above.`

So `search` here is the object on the scope created by `ng-model` and which has properties bound to input elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
ex:

$scope.friends =[{
  "name":"abc",
  "phone":985878
},
{
  "name":"xyz",
  "phone":985878
}
]

search.name will filter based on name
search.phone will filter based on phone number
search.$ will filter both name and phone number
```

ex [angularjs doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Comment: Thanks, but I understand that, thats' what is written in the manual. My question is what is `search` word exactly? Why it's there?

Comment: filter:search:strict  here search is a column name which you want to filter

Comment: I've figured out the answer myself. Thanks for the  `filter:search:strict` hint, I didn't see it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Here `search` is an object that you are passing as `expression` in following line.

```
<tr ng-repeat="friendObj in friends | filter:search:strict">
```

So in `ng-model` you are saying `search.$`, `search.name` & `search.phone`.

Let's say you put `a` in input `search.$` it replaces `filter:search:strict` with `filter:{$:'a'}:strict`.

when you put `a` in input `search.name` it replaces `filter:search:strict` with `filter:{name:'a'}:strict`.

when you put `a` in input `search.phone` it replaces `filter:search:strict` with `filter:{phone:'a'}:strict`.